# Swap numerals in a String by byte operation

Tags: java, string, bit-manipulation, byte, str-replace

I have a long String containing literals (both upper and lowercase) and numerals (0 to 9).

I am doing some byte operations on that string. So for example I am replacing all uppercase literals with their lowercase equivalents like this:

```
byte[] bytes = myString.getBytes();

for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    if(bytes[i] >= 'A' && bytes[i] <= 'Z')
        bytes[i] = (byte)( 'a' + (bytes[i] - 'A'));
}

myString = new String(bytes);
```

I also want to swap all numerals i.e. replace all 0 by 9, all 1 by 8 and so on the same way but couldn't figure out the exact statement. I tried:

```
if(bytes[i] >= '0' && bytes[i] <= '9') bytes[i] = (byte)( '0' + (bytes[i] - '9'));
```

but it just adds some special chars to my output, so I think the if statement is wrong. Any idea how to swap those numerals in a byte operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your order of operands is wrong.

```
bytes[i] = (byte)( '9' - (bytes[i] - '0'));
```

When doing stuff like this, always have an ascii table at hand http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the special chars when manipulating digits, you have the subtraction the wrong way round:

```
'0' + (bytes[i] - '9')
```

should be

```
'0' + ('9' - bytes[i])
```

---

If you are manipulating characters, use `String.toCharArray()`, not `String.getBytes()`: `String` is logically a `char[]`, not `byte[]`.

Single characters in the string may be converted to two bytes; doing arithmetic on individual bytes may result in you changing "half" of the character, which will probably lead to funky results when you try to convert it back to a string.

You can do pretty much the same thing using chars instead:

```
char[] chars = myString.toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    if(chars[i] >= 'A' && chars[i] <= 'Z')
        chars[i] = (char) ('a' + (chars[i] - 'A'));
}

myString = new String(chars);
```

It would be much easier to read and less error-prone to use `Character.toLowercase(chars[i])` (similar methods exist for digits), rather than doing arithmetic on character values.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use to replace numbers like the same way you are replacing the lower to upper and vice versa. Because ASCII values for numbers are in series and you are going beyond that limit. Instead of that you have to try 10 if conditions like this;

```
if(bytes[i] == '0')
    bytes[i] = '9'
else if(bytes[i] == '1')
    bytes[i] = '8'
```

And so on....